# How to present cursor from two columns of the same table to SimpleCursorAdapter Android

Tags: android

I a developing an app whereby i retrieve data from an sqlite database and the data is displayed on a listview I am retrieving data from two columns of a specific table and it is added to a SimpleCursorAdapter which is then set to the listview i would like to display each record in the different columns to be displayed on its own row currently data from both columns is displayed in one row any help will be appreciated especially a link to a working example

i have deicded to add my code maybe this will help you help me even better

```
mDicCursor=managedQuery(DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
              new String[] {query}, null);

      if (mDicCursor == null ) {
          mTextView.setText(getString(R.string.no_results, new Object[] {query}));
    /*    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
            dialog.setTitle("WORD MISSING");*/
            showDialog(DIALOG_WORDMISSING);


       //new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Argh").setMessage("Watch out!").setNeutralButton("Close", null).show();  
      } else {
          int count = mDicCursor.getCount();
          String countString = getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.search_results,
                                  count, new Object[] {count, query});
          mTextView.setText(countString);


/*  int  iWord = mDicCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DictDatabase.REC_DESCRIPTION);
    mTextView.setText(mDicCursor.getString(iWord));*/
     // Specify the columns we want to display in the result

    String[] from = new String[]{ DictDatabase.REC_WORD,
            DictDatabase.REC_DESCRIPTION   };




       // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
     int[] to = new int[]{ R.id.text2,
                           R.id.text3};
      SimpleCursorAdapter words = 
         new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.dictwords, mDicCursor, from, to);

      mListView.setAdapter(words);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your cursor adapter, you can detail how the data is set up and presented on the screen. You need to ensure that every 2nd row comes from the second column. This can be done using modulus on the current row index

```
boolean isEvenRow = (currentRow % 2==0); // will give 0 for even rows, 1 for odd rows
```

And then you can use this boolean result to choose whether the data comes from Column A or Column B.

```
String data;
if (isEvenRow){
 data = mCursor.getString(COLUMN_A);
}else{
 data = mCursor.getString(COLUMN_B);
}
```

And then you also need to ensure that the count of total rows is going to be double the size of the cursor, so when you are returning the count, make sure you return the correct value:

```
return mCursor.getCount()*2;
```

This will allow you to scroll double the length of the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Create an another layout which is containi ng 2 textviews and place them next to each other. In  your activity "R.layout.new_layout" and use this in your simplecursoradapter's constructor with your new 2 textviews id.m
Example :

```
SimpleCursorAdapter simple=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.new_layout,cursor, new String[]{column1,column2} , new int[] {textview1,textview2});
```